# How is to use eloquent in Laravel with 3 tables?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have this Database Table which is related to each other

1 customer can have 1 or more tires and 1 tire can have 3 or more test as example below

and I want to get the output of this below using customer_id

I have idea on query builder but I just want to know to use eloquent relation in this case? Anyone can gave me advice?

Can anyone show me example to do this using Eloquent ORM Relationship?

Thankyou

```
customer_id     customer     manufacturer    trademark      test
1               Jeddah       Pirelli         Str Scorpio    High Speed
1               Jeddah       Pirelli         Str Scorpio    Endurance
1               Jeddah       Pirelli         Str Scorpio    Visual
```

First Table : tbl_customer

```
id = 1 //unique id
letter_number = 520
customer = Jeddah
```

Second Table : tbl_tire

```
id = 1 //unique id
customer_id = 1
manufacturer = Pirelli
trademark = Str Ccorpio
```

Third Table : tbl_test

```
id = 1 //unique id
tire_id = 1
customer_id = 1
test = High Speed

id = 2
tire_id = 1
customer_id = 1
test = Endurance

id = 3
tire_id = 1
customer_id = 1
test = Visual
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you already know `customer_id`, do this:

```
$tires = Tire::where('customer_id', $customerId)->with('tests')->get();
```

This will create 2 queries, but tests will be kind of nested (not like in your example) which is better since it's more comfortable to work with data in this case.